# md-dialog renders behind other Material Design elements, and not centred

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I've set up a basic md-dialog component, and it is displaying. However, it gets shoved to the bottom left of the page, and is behind other material design elements which I'm using on that page.

[image]

I have tried setting the z-index of every element but no joy. Please some advice!

Comment: The material theme does not seem to be loaded.

Comment: How do I add the material theme? I don't think I've actually added a theme yet.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming